# Как выцепить номер телефона с помощью python

Tags: python, парсер, request

Есть страничка https://kaluga.masterpotolkov.com/contacts/
На ней я вижу номер телефона +7 (4842) 21-06-52
Но когда смотрю код страницы, либо пытаюсь найти его после get запроса - такого номера нет, вместо него есть номер +7 (4842) 27-22-22
Как это возможно и как мне всё-таки можно выцепить нужный номер? Спасибо

Comment: Не увидел на той странице 21-06-52, только 27-22-22: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrTwe.png

Comment: А тот телефон можно вытащить через css-селектор `.page-contacts-info a.phone_substetute`

Comment: зашёл сейчас - там совсем другой номер) Походу, он генерится заново, периодически, но в коде страницы остаётся 27-22-22

Comment: А что мешает лично вам заглянуть в куки? риторический вопрос ))

Answer (score 0):

в кукисах

```
roistat_phone: +7 (4842) 21-03-88,+7 (4842) 21-09-33
roistat_phone_script_data: [{"phone":"+7 (4842) 21-03-88","css_selectors":[".phone_substetute",".roistat-phone"],"replaceable_numbers":[]},{"phone":"+7 (4842) 21-09-33","css_selectors":[".tel-ka"],"replaceable_numbers":["79005773974"]}]
```